# list all words containing an arg

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "words",
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
const searchWord = args
      if(!searchWord) return;
const dictionary = require('../../json/dictionary');
      const words = await dictionary.fetch()
    message.channel.send(`.. ${words.filter((msg) => msg.content.has(searchWord))}`)
 }
}


 }
}
```

I'm trying to get words that contains an arg but the code won't work also, I got an error `TypeError: dictionary.fetch is not a function` and I guess that's not the only problem. Any way to fix it?

Comment: So what's in `../../json/dictionary.js`?

Comment: I guess I don't have to send it here... It's a list of all words in a dictionary (probably not all)

Comment: if its an array, then it wont have some magic fetch() method, also you don't define searchWord anywhere, more effort is required

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF require('your_file') RETURNS A JSON VALUE**

If the content of your dictionary is an array, juste declare words like this

```
const words = JSON.parse(dictionary);
// words = ["word", "word", "another word", "..."]
```

Else if the content is an Object ("{}"), declare words like that

```
const words = Object.keys(JSON.parse(dictionary));
// words = ["word", "word", "another word", "..."]
```

> if the word is in the key, it is Object.keys, if it is the value then put Object.values instead.

The JSON.parse method will get the JSON in the file.
The Object.keys will only take the Keys of an Object.